# Error in creating table (Postgis)

Tags: geometry, psycopg2

I am trying to write a python function to run PostGIS query:

```
import psycopg2

connection = psycopg2.connect(database="postgresdb",user="postgres", password="pass123")

print "Opened database successfully"

curs = connection.cursor()

curs.execute('''CREATE TABLE Kuniyil (

                system_index varchar(20),

                area         float,

                kcount       integer,

                label        integer,

               filename     varchar(64),

               geojson      text,

               geom         geometry(Polygon,4326)
  );''')

print "Table created successfully"

connection.commit()
connection.close()
```

But as I ran code above, I got this error:

```
**Opened database successfully
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "post1.py", line 15, in <module>
    );''')
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: type "geometry" does not exist
LINE 8:   geom         geometry(Polygon,4326)**
```

How to edit this code to make it run smoothly?

Comment: Does your database based on postgis? Also add release of pgadmin and PostgreSQL.

Comment: yes. database based on postgis.....  Realease of:  psql (PostgreSQL) 9.5.5,   pgAdmin III 1.22.2

Comment: OK, it looks strange. Still try add first `curs.execute('create extension postgis')` and then your `curs.execute` and tell me if it helps.

Comment: No. Its not working.. Now I got this error:Opened database successfully
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "post1.py", line 7, in <module>
    curs.execute('create extension postgis')
psycopg2.InternalError: could not load library "/usr/lib/postgresql/9.5/lib/postgis-2.3.so": /usr/lib/liblwgeom-2.3.so.0: undefined symbol: GEOSClipByRect

Comment: try to use linux terminal command `apt-get install liblwgeom-2.3` (if you use one-of-the-Linux-OS)

Comment: already Installed.When i use this commamd it shows  Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'liblwgeom-2.3-0' for regex 'liblwgeom-2.3'
liblwgeom-2.3-0 is already the newest version (2.3.1+dfsg-1.pgdg16.04+1).
liblwgeom-2.3-0 set to manually installed.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 336 not upgraded.

Comment: Still I got previous error...

Comment: Please do not use comments to add information to your question. Comments exist to *request* clarification, but that information belongs in the question body.  It's not fair to those who would answer your question to need to mine critical details from comments. Please **edit the question** to contain all details added as comments *and* format the code legibly by indenting using the `{}` button.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your input there is nothing wrong with your code.

The error you supply in the comments:

```
psycopg2.InternalError: could not load library "/usr/lib/postgresql/9.5/lib/postgis-2.3.so": /usr/lib/liblwgeom-2.3.so.0: undefined symbol: GEOSClipByRect
```

Is an error thrown by PostgreSQL when you are trying to create the postgis extension, related to the liblwgeom package. I'm having related problems myself, trying to install postgis 2.3 on postgres 9.6 on Ubuntu Trusty, but so far I am  unable to fix it.